# Android - How can I locate the tab indicator between the two tab TextViews?

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager, indicator

As far as I know, there are components `ViewPager` and `ActionBar` can support "tab navigation" mode but they don't have intermediate tab indicator between the tabs, just only positioning below a tab `TextView`.

How the Google Play app implemented this feature: **POSITIONING linked with transition** ?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve this by implementing [`android:actionBarTabStyle`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#actionBarTabStyle) using [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) library.

### Update:

I don't have idea exactly about this, but hope you know Android team has integrated the same pattern in I/O 2013 Android app and it will open sourced soon.

### Update 2:

I just came across one library which can fulfill your requirement, check this: https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip

Comment: thanks for response, but I believe there is no possibilities in the style elements: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Style. Notice that the two fragments("TOP PAID", "TOP FREE") are currently transition state.

Comment: Yes you are right about transition state but that [**actionBarTabStyle**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#actionBarTabStyle) is possible as I have already implemented in many of the projects and changed color of that indicator too.

Comment: Um.. but I want to know is *how position* the indicator reflecting transition state, *not coloring* or shaping.

Comment: is it possible to add custom tabs in pagerslidingtabstrip?