# Android - Animate/Slide Action Bar Tabs

Tags: android, animation, tabs, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have an Activity with 4 action bar tabs, each one is a different fragment.  I have my own TabListener class which implements ActionBar.TabListener to manage the fragments as they change.

However what I want is for a user to click a different tab and the tab indicator to slide over to the new tab in a smooth animation.  I tried setting a custom animation for my fragment transactions but that doesn't affect the tab indicator.

Is this possible?  And if so could someone point me in the right direction?

I have looked through a lot of posts but I'm still unclear as to whether this is possible using the standard android SDK (no third party libraries like ActionBarSherlock) and ActionBar tabs.  Plus searching for it yields mainly results for sliding between tabs or animating fragment transactions, nothing relating to the indicator.

Any help whatsoever would be appreciated.

Comment: Check out this Q&A; there's a nicely done project on github
http://stackoverflow.com/a/16475576/163936